# Primefaces event not supported by composite component

Tags: events, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component, primefaces-extensions

I have a problem with composite component. I want use pe:javascript (call from normal site) inside composite component. It's possible ?? I try use insertChildren, but I have error: "Event dataSelect is not supported by composite component"

Composite Component.xhtml:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

        <!-- INTERFACE -->
        <cc:interface>
            <cc:attribute name="label"/>
            <cc:attribute name="value"/>
            <cc:attribute name="pattern"/>
            <cc:attribute name="size"/>
            <cc:attribute name="required"/>
            <cc:attribute name="showButtonPanel" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false"/>
            <cc:attribute name="showOn"/>
            <cc:attribute name="converterMessage"/>
            <cc:attribute name="koloruj" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false"/>
        </cc:interface>

        <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
        <cc:implementation>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="#{cc.attrs.koloruj}">
                    <p:calendar  id="dateFrom" label="#{cc.attrs.label}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" pattern="#{cc.attrs.pattern}" size="#{cc.attrs.size}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
                                 showButtonPanel="#{cc.attrs.showButtonPanel}"
                                 showOn="#{cc.attrs.showOn}"
                                 converterMessage="#{cc.attrs.converterMessage}"
                                 beforeShowDay="kolorujKalendarz"
                                 >       
                            <cc:insertChildren/>
                    </p:calendar>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <p:calendar  id="dateFrom" label="#{cc.attrs.label}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" pattern="#{cc.attrs.pattern}" size="#{cc.attrs.size}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
                                 showButtonPanel="#{cc.attrs.showButtonPanel}"
                                 showOn="#{cc.attrs.showOn}"
                                 converterMessage="#{cc.attrs.converterMessage}"
                                 >
<cc:insertChildren/>
                    </p:calendar>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </cc:implementation>
    </html>
```

how want I use it

```
                <my:mycalendar id="dateFrom" label="aaa" value="#{wniosekUrlopowyForm.dateFrom}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" size="10" required="true"
                         showButtonPanel="true"
                         showOn="button"
                         converterMessage=""
                         >
                <f:convertDateTime id="convertDateFrom" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" for="dateFrom:dateFrom"/>
                <pe:javascript event="dateSelect" execute="setUrlopTime('end');"/>
            </my:mycalendar >
```

Comment: Have you tried `<p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="setUrlopTime('end');"/>` instead of the `pe:javascript`?

Comment: the same problem: <p:ajax> Composite component does not support event dateSelect